# ssh ncat keeps ncat process running after disconnect; how do I prevent that?

Tags: ssh, process

If I run the command

```
$ ssh othermachine ncat localhost 10000
```

that opens an `ssh` session to "othermachine" and pipes it into an `ncat` process. (There's something else listening on "othermachine" port 10000).

Now if I disconnect the `ssh` session (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) the `ncat` process on "othermachine" keeps running. How do I prevent that? I want `ncat` to die if its parent ssh exits.

Answer (score 4):

Technically when you `ssh` to "othermachine" you're remotely running `ncat localhost 10000` on "othermachine". There is no piping going on here.

As to something else "listening" I do not believe there is anything. Rather you're running `ncat localhost 10000` attempting to connect to something that's listening on port 10000 and there isn't anything there.

#### Example

```
$ ncat localhost 10000
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

If you tell `ncat` to listen then it will stay open.

```
$ ncat localhost -l 10000
```

Putting this together your command works as is, with the addition of the `-l` switch.

```
$ ssh othermachine ncat localhost -l 10000
```

#### ncat continues to run?

After performing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> `ncat localhost -l 10000` too continues to run on the remote server for me as well.

To stop this behavior you could wrap the call to "othermachine" inside of a shell, such as `sh`.

#### Example

```
$ ssh othermachine -t 'sh -c "ncat localhost -l 10000"'
...stays up...
```

Now in another shell if I login to "othermachine" and confirm it's running:

```
$ pgrep -l ncat
8479 ncat
```

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the original `ssh` connection `ncat` stops running as well.

```
$ ssh othermachine -t 'sh -c "ncat localhost -l 10000"'
Ctrl + C
Shared connection to othermachine closed.
```

Confirming it's gone:

```
$ pgrep -l ncat
$
```

#### Why does this work?

The key piece in this setup is the `-t` switch. This forces the connection to setup a pseudo-tty (ptty) terminal as part of the connection.

*excerpt from ssh man page*

```
 -t     Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary
        screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
        e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty 
        allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

This ptty allows us to send the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> through to `ncat` which is then terminated, resulting in the closing of the `ssh` connection entirely.

#### References

- [SSH inside SSH fails with “stdin: is not a tty”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48527/ssh-inside-ssh-fails-with-stdin-is-not-a-tty)
- [SSH output isn't line buffered?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21920/ssh-output-isnt-line-buffered/21921#21921)
- [How can I run a script immediately after connecting via SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/how-can-i-run-a-script-immediately-after-connecting-via-ssh/9910#9910)
- [ssh via multiple hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/ssh-via-multiple-hosts/25056#25056)

Comment: By "something else listening" I mean that there is a different program already running on 'othermachine' and listening on port 10000, so this answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at `man ssh`

```
If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.
```

This could be the cause why it keep running after a `SIGTERM/SIGKILL`. If you want to force a shell login you will need to do something like:

```
ssh othermachine -t 'bash -l -c "ncat localhost 10000"'
```

Comment: I did a quick test with iperf(`ssh othermachine -t 'bash -l -c "iperf -s "'`) and it worked. Without calling explicitly bash, it will keep running ;)

Answer (score 0):

nwildner's answer works, but the only thing I'm worried about is that the -t switch assigns a pseudo-tty, and that could perhaps result in terminal escape sequences not passing through cleanly? 
In the case of forwarding with `ncat`, a better solution for my case is to use

`ssh othermachine -W localhost:10000`

which is ssh's native way to forward the connection.

Comment: I do prefer the remote host execution instead forcing a login shell too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to this question is to use `nc` instead of `ncat`. It generally has the same functionality. If ncat's stdin is closed, ncat does not close its end of the tcp connection, while nc does.